# Android merchant acount pay via Paypal

Tags: android, paypal, android-account, merchant-account

Pro.

I am in Viet Nam. Google doesn't allow to upload paid app from my country. I would like to ask my friend (he's living at Czech) to create a merchant account. After that, I want to connect my paypal account to this account to receive money from Google. Can i do it? Any suggest, please?

Comment: I dont think this is possible because when you try to upload the application at that time Google will track your location and might not allow you to upload the application.

Comment: really? Hix, that's too bad. God, when goole will allow to uplpad paid app in here? :(